# How to use .filter() and .includes() methods on JSON with multiple conditions (JS, React)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Apologies if there's a simple answer to this, as I am new to programming. I'm trying to build a web app that filters a selection of quotes based on keywords. I have a selection of quotes formatted in JSON, here's a snippet:

```
  [
    {
      "description": "quote 1",
      "source": "source a",
      "keywords": ["filter1"]
    },
    {
      "description": "quote 2",
      "source": "source b",
      "keywords": ["filter1", "filter2"]
    },
]
```

My current code that does the filtering looks like:

```
quotes.filter((el) => el.keywords.includes(...usersKeywords));
```

`quotes` is the JSON data above, and `usersKeywords` is an array of keywords the user has selected (as strings) as filters.

Currently, my code successfully filters the JSON to return a quote, so long as it includes *at least* one keyword. That is, "quote 2" will be included so long as "filter1" **OR** "filter" was selected. Ideally, I only want a quote to appear if all its keywords are selected.

How do I change my filter so that **all** the keywords must be present for the quote to return?

Comment: Try using `.every()` to indicate that every `el.keywords` should be found in `usersKeywords`: `quotes.filter((el) => el.keywords.every(kw => usersKeywords.includes(kw)));`

Comment: Or maybe you meant that every `userKeywords` must be present in the current `el.keywords`? `quotes.filter((el) => userKeywords.every(kw => el.keywords.includes(kw)));`

Comment: @slappy seems right. Can you put it as an answer please?

Comment: @LudovitMydla: That's more responsibility than I can handle at the moment. I'll let someone else bear that burden this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, you only check for first element of **usersKeywords** to be present in your quotes's keywords array. There could be a bug if any of quotes's keywords array element not be present at **userKeywords** first element. On this case you won't get expected result according to your below code.

```
quotes.filter((el) => el.keywords.includes(...usersKeywords));
```

According to your question, If you want a quote to appear if all its keywords are selected, then you should apply [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method on **usersKeywords** array. 
Something like below

```
const quotes = [
    {
      "description": "quote 1",
      "source": "source a",
      "keywords": ["filter1"]
    },
    {
      "description": "quote 2",
      "source": "source b",
      "keywords": ["filter1", "filter2"]
    },
];
const usersKeywords = ["filter1", "filter2"];
const res = quotes.filter(q => usersKeywords.every(key => q.keywords.includes(key)));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Seems obvious now, so I appreciate the support, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
quotes.filter((el) => userKeywords.every(key_word => el.keywords.includes(key_word)));
```

This will check whether all the elements in the userKeywords are present in your keyword of your quote element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for test every user keyword

```js
const quotes = [
    {
        description: 'quote 1',
        source: 'source a',
        keywords: ['filter1'],
    },
    {
        description: 'quote 2',
        source: 'source b',
        keywords: ['filter1', 'filter2'],
    },
];
const usersKeywords = ['filter2', 'filter1'];

const result = quotes.filter(q => usersKeywords.every(k => q.keywords.includes(k)));

console.log(result);
```